# REST API with Spring and Angular login

Tags: angular, spring

Is there a way to log in in angular with users validation from the REST API table Users?

I need to make a table users and when I run the API method to create 1 user with his password. Then, I need to make a login and check if the user and pass are in the API table.

I searched a lot but I didn't find anything good. I'm using Angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good answer but you can try these things :

- Making a POST request to your API to create a user provided with a form made with Angular : https://angular.io/guide/forms
- Then make a GET request with some params (user+password) to the API to check if this couple exists in the backend database

Not sure if that helped but you can try it :)

Cheers